How to display a GeoServer vector tile service in maplibre
Generally speaking, I was stuck in a maplibre problem.


Here is the detail:
I initialized a maplibre map with multiple tile layers，and it works as shown above。
Then I'd like to add a vector tile layer which published by GeoServer.
The layer can  display correctly with OpenLayers,the URL is:
http://203.83.232.18:9090/geoserver/gwc/demo/postgis:a_jianzhumian_bj2k?gridSet=EPSG:900913&format=application/vnd.mapbox-vector-tile

I added the layer in to a map:


      map.on("load", () => {
        map.addSource("local_pbf", {
          type: "vector",
          data: "http://192.168.1.29:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/qrazy:street@EPSG:900913@pbf/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf",
          minzoom: 0,
          maxzoom: 18,
          scheme: "tms",
        });

        map.addLayer({
          id: "local_pbf",
          type: "line",
          source: "local_pbf",
          "source-layer": "street",
          layout: {
            "line-join": "round",
            "line-cap": "round",
          },
          paint: {
            "line-color": "#ff69b4",
            "line-width": 1,
          },
        });
      });



I can't get the layer "street" displayed in the map,but an error "  GET http://192.168.1.29:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/qrazy:street@EPSG:900913@pbf/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.pbf 400 (Bad Request)"。
I'm so confused that maplibre can not parse the url "http://192.168.1.29:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/qrazy:street@EPSG:900913@pbf/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.pbf" to the extent of the current map,
What's the problem in my code? How can I solve it?

I have used geoserver pbfs in mapbox GL a few years ago - can it be that you need to invert the y parameter like {-y}
